# RSpec: Stubbing helper params not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm currently writing a helper spec at the moment. Part of the spec involves stubbing the params hash. My spec is as follows:

```
example do
  helper.stub(:params) { { user_type: :aupair, first_name: "John", second_name: "Doe", country: "Ireland" } }
  pp helper.params
  expect(no_search_params?).to be_false
end
```

When I pp the helper.params hash here, I get the expected content back. However, when I print it in the method I'm speccing, I get a blank hash. The method is just a stub at the moment:

```
def no_search_params?
  pp params
  true
end
```

Why are my stubbed params from my spec not carrying over into the helper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to correctly invoke the helper for the spec using:

```
expect(helper.no_search_params?).to be_false
```

instead of

```
expect(no_search_params?).to be_false
```

Comment: This resolved my issue. What is the difference betweeen calling helper.no_search_params? and no_search_params? They both call the same method but with different values for the params hash.

Comment: There's some weirdness around how rspec creates its helper context which someone more knowledgeable than I will have to explain.  The basic version is that helper.no_search_params? calls the method on the helper object, where no_search_params? calls the method on on your rspec context.

Comment: Suprised this one hasn't been upvoted more.  Thanks! @gmacdougall